# how to update all the keys in mongoDb document

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have a collection that has a complex structure, and the documents in this structures are different in the structure. I want to update all the keys `V` to have value `0` in this collection. 
Example:

```
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5805dfa519f972b200ea2955"),
    "s" : {
        "id" : NumberLong(36435)
    },
    "a" : [ 
        {
            "XX-(random value)" : {
                "V" : 4
            },
            "V" : 4,
            "u" : {
                "YY-(random value)" : {
                    "V" : 4,
                    "ZZ-(random value)" : {
                        "V" : 4,
                        "WW-(random value)" : {
                            "V" : 4
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all I suggest you change your document structure and make the `xx-*` filed a key value in the subdocument. That being said to answer your question, the only way to do this with the current structure to take a snapshot of your documents; iterate the cursor then update each document using bulk operations.

Comment: can you please send me code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a short javascript.  You need to iterate through each property of each document, checking the name of the property.  If it matches the name "V" then update it with the value 0.  This can be done recursively using a loop.  The following javascript code should do the needful:

```
function checkProperties(doc) {
    for (var propertyName in doc) {
        if (typeof doc[propertyName] == "object") {
            checkProperties(doc[propertyName]);
        } else {
            if (propertyName == "V") {
                doc[propertyName] = 0;
                print(doc[propertyName]);
            }
        }
    }
}

db.<your_collection_name>.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    checkProperties(doc);
    db.<your_collection_name>.save(doc);
});
```

If you save this code in a .js file you can then run it against your mongo database:

```
> mongo --host <host> --port <port> <script_name>.js
```